# Why echo not exit

Tags: bash, echo, pipeline

```
echo aaa > >(echo $(cat))
```

In my opinion, it should print "aaa" and exit, but it stops unless I press enter button, why?

Thx

Comment: echo aaa  - should print aaa and then exit

Comment: @ArvindDhakad But it's redirecting to the process substitution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not waiting for you to press enter before it finishes. The command finishes immediately, but its output is printed after the next shell prompt. it looks like:

```
barmar@dev:~$ echo aaa > >(echo $(cat))
barmar@dev:~$ aaa
```

This is because the shell doesn't wait for the command in the process substitution to finish, it just waits for the `echo` command to complete. So it prints the next prompt as soon as the `echo` is done, and then `echo $(cat)` runs asynchronously and prints its output.

If you type another command at this point, it will work. It just looks weird because the output was printed after the prompt. You only need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> if you want a new prompt on its own line.

Comment: adding `; wait $!` after will wait for last process termination

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul That only waits for background processes created with `&`.

Comment: `echo aaa > >(echo $BASHPID;sleep 1;echo $(cat)) ; echo $!; wait $!
`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul No, it contains the PID of the last background process.

Comment: I get an error: `bash: wait: pid 8849 is not a child of this shell`

Comment: ok, maybe it depends on bash versions 4.4.12 it works but not in 4.2.53

Comment: Yep, I have 4.2.37.

Comment: Having the process substitution set the value of `$!` as well is a new feature in 4.4.

Answer (score 2):

`$(cat)` is the same as the

```
`cat`
```

command. It runs `cat` and is expanded to its output.

But without any arguments `cat` (actually `/bin/cat`, see [cat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html)) is reading the *stdin* and copying it into *stdout* till end of file.

So your shell is running that, so is waiting for your input.

The shell is [expanding](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) in  specific order.

Comment: The process substitution means it should get its input from `echo aaa`.

Comment: well `echo aaa > >(echo $(cat))` this work in my ubuntu 16.04 without any problem?, it print aaa. Wondering why?

Comment: The question I think is why it is waiting for Enter and not exiting immediately after printing... - Also for some reason it execute what ever input given, try: `echo -e "aaa" > >(echo $(cat))`, type `ls /tmp`, enter....

Comment: To me, I didn't press enter to exit. I just copy pasted the code and it print `aaa` and exited gracefully, that's why bit confusing.

Comment: btw barmar answer explains why :)